# What is the syntax for casting a reference to a variable in Swift?

Tags: swift

Being new to Swift (and having some issues with Swift's pointer handling) I'm unable to properly parse the errors Xcode gives me. Any tips on getting a reference into a variable?

`RGBA` is a *just* struct of 4 `UInt8`s

```
var data: UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA> = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA>(CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext))
var pixel = &data[offset] // [1] this is the trouble statement

// use the pixel struct to read *and* write
```

[1] Errors

- 'myclass.RGBA' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer'
- Type 'inout myclass.RGBA' of variable is not materializable

How come I am able to access the memory using the subscript operator (`data[offset].r = 0`) but I have use the `memory` property after setting the element reference (`var pixel = data[offset]`)? Surely there must be a Swift way for storing a reference in a local?

I can also accomplish the same through an `inout` parameter function, ie;

```
func setPixel(inout pixel: RGBA, var r: UInt8, var g: UInt8, var b: UInt8, var a: UInt8) {
  pixel.r = r // I can use pixel directly without '.memory'
}
```

Comment: What about `var pixel = data[offset]` ?

Comment: That doesn't seem to allow me to write to the underlying memory. That only allows me to change a copy of what's contained in data[offset].

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an offset to the pointer:

```
let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<RGBA>(CGBitmapContextGetData(bitmapContext))
let pixel = data + offset
```

Then you can read/write the memory pointed to by `pixel`:

```
let red = pixel.memory.red
pixel.memory.blue = 123
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @jacobsd: Well, then I misunderstood your question. At least the first version of your question asked for a replacement to `var pixel = &data[offset]` so that `pixel` can be used to read and write the data.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research (including talking to the #swift folks), it appears that Swift deliberately prohibits this kind of variable reference (reference to an array element).

One solution is to use a function to scope the reference:

```
func setElem(inout elem: T, var value: T {
  elem = value
}

// can then be used like (which works for address-of array element):
self.setElem(&data[index], elemValue)
```